# Circle around div when hover

Tags: html, css

I have a sun shape div. I just want to show a border when hover it with transparent gap between hover border and object.

[image]

First I tried with box shadow but cant make white gap. It requires solid color, then I tried with this way. But the gap is not appearing.

Here is my code.

```css
    .sun-quote-pages{
      border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #f4953b;
        width: 4.1em;
        height: 4.1em;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    }
    
    .sun-quote-pages:hover {
         transform: scale(1.3);
        border: 2px solid #f4953b;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 2px; 
    }
    
    
    .wrapper{
      margin-left:150px;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
      </div> 
    </div>
```

What am I missing here?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsb6y0rc/4/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is 'background-clip' found here:

https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

With it you can prevent the background color from flowing under the border and padding. It is widely supported:

https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip

so your CSS would become:

```
.sun-quote-pages{
  border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f4953b;
    width: 4.1em;
    height: 4.1em;
    padding: 2px; 
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, border 0.5s ease;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
    border: 2px solid #f4953b;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}


.wrapper{
  margin-left:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/auzjv4rp/11

Or why not have a double border?

See: https://jsfiddle.net/auzjv4rp/13

Comment: Very nice indeed. I didn't know that property! Thanks

Comment: This is good, But border is visible on normal state also. I need that border only in hover.

Comment: @Janath I've changed the answer so the border appears when you hover over it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.sun-quote-pages:hover {
         transform: scale(1.3);
       
    }
 .sun-quote-pages:hover::after {
        border: 2px solid #f4953b;
       
    }
 
 .sun-quote-pages{
 width: 4.1em;
 height: 4.1em;
 margin: 20px auto;
 border-style: ridge;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 border-spacing:10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position:relative;
 background-color: #f4953b;
 transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
 }
 .sun-quote-pages:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   left: -10px;
   right: -10px;
   bottom: -10px;
   border: 2px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 50%;
   }

    
    
    .wrapper{
      margin-left:150px;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
      </div> 
    </div>
 <style>
```

Try This..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.sun-quote-pages{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #f4953b;
    width: 4.1em;
    height: 4.1em;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
border: solid 2px #f4953b;
  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: content-box; /* support: IE9+ */
  background-color: #f4953b;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.wrapper{
  margin-left:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
  </div> 
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpow9ahc/

Comment: It's because of margin?

Comment: It's because off padding, we can add `box-sizing: border-box`; for `.sun-quote-pages` div

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like using `:before` property.
    Add following CSS and try:

```
.sun-quote-pages:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;  
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover:before {
    border: 2px solid #f4953b;
}
```

See JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qsb6y0rc/75/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `sun` element with `background-color`, `shadow` and `border` with `width: 0`

```
<div class="sun"></div>

.sun {
    background-color: #f4953b;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #f3f5f6 inset;
    border: solid 0 #f4953b;
    transition: border-width 0.3s linear;
}
```

Then on hover, just animate the `border-width`:

```
.sun:hover {
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qsb6y0rc/70/):

Answer (score 0):

You can use css pseudo selector `:after`, which size is bigger than the original element. Set this element `transparent` background and the same border color as the original element like this:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.sun-quote-pages{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f4953b;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease;
}

.sun-quote-pages::after {
  content: "\00a0";
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid #f4953b;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0.5s;
  transform: translate(-5px,-5px);
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper{
  margin-left:150px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">   
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `radial-gradient`

```css
.sun-quote-pages {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:
   radial-gradient(circle at center,#f4953b 54%,transparent 56%,transparent 65%,#f4953b 66%);
  background-color: #f4953b;
  width: 4.1em;
  height: 4.1em;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}

.sun-quote-pages:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color:transparent;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sun-quote-pages">
  </div>
</div>
```